# asp dropdownlist dynamic value from javascript issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with 5 items. Value of last item is "other". By choosing "other" appears popup with input. The value of this input i set to this item by javascript. So value becoms inserted text. When i submitting the form, it doesn't work with this dynamic value, but other items of select works. Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: Submit the form will `post back` the page, any thing you do in the client side will vanish unless it send data back to server, which is, AJAX.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to set the value of the item?

Comment: Access the dynamic value by using the Request.Params collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than set this value as droupdown list item value, you can use hiden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" runat="server" />
```

set value using JavaScript as below

```
document.getElementById ("hiddenField").value = "inputValue";
```

hiddenField value can access from code behind as below

```
string inputValue = hiddenField.Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick example of using Request.Params collection to read dynamically added value.

Here is the client side code.

```
<!-- Server Control - Drop Down List -->
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<!-- Control to fire JS event to add a new item to the Drop Down List above -->
<input type="button" value="Add Item D" id="AddItem" />

<!-- jQuery event to add a new option to the list on the click (no postback) -->
$('#AddItem').click(function ()
{
    $('#<%= ddList.ClientID %>').append('<option value="D">D</option>');
});
```

Here is the server side code to read the value.

```
var ddlListSelectedValue = Request.Params["ddList"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Update you Function

```
$('#AddItem').click(function ()
{
var dropdown= document.getElementById("<%= ddList.ClientID %>");
dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('YOUR TEXT', 'YOUR VALUE');
});
```

Cheers




I have tested it myself, it works. Following is a complete example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test ddl Item Addition By IuR</title>
</head>
<body onload="add_dditem()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_dditem()
{
var dropdown= document.getElementById("ddList");
dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('YOUR TEXT', 'YOUR VALUE');
}
</script>

<select id="ddList">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```