# Getting text from asp.net dropdownlist which is populated with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I populated asp.net dropdownlists with jquery to show countries and cities. The dropdownlists show the correct value. I need to get the text of a ddlState at the backend of asp.net. However, I cannot get the selected text from the dropdownlist. It said it is null.

Below is my script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetCountries();
        GetStates();

    });
    function GetCountries() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=en&style=full&username=xxx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".ddlCountry").append($('<option />', { value: -1, text: 'Select Country' }));
                $(data.geonames).each(function (index, item) {
                    $(".ddlCountry").append($('<option />', { value: item.geonameId, text: item.countryName}));
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Failed to get countries.");
            }
        });
    }

    function GetStates() {
        $(".ddlCountry").change(function () {
            GetChildren($(this).val(), "States", $(".ddlState"));
        });


    }


    function GetChildren(geoNameId, childType, ddlSelector) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + geoNameId + "&username=xxx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $(ddlSelector).empty();
                $(ddlSelector).append($('<option />', { value: -1, text: 'Select ' + childType }));
                $(data.geonames).each(function (index, item) {
                    $(ddlSelector).append($('<option />', { value: item.geonameId, text: item.name + "," + item.countryCode }));
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed to get data");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Below is the two dropdownlists that i have.

```
 <asp:DropDownList
                    runat="server"
                    ID="ddlCountry"
                    CssClass="ddlCountry">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <asp:DropDownList
                    runat="server"
                    ID="ddlState"
                    onChange="ddlState_OnChange"
                    CssClass="ddlState">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: When and how are you trying to get the selected text?

Comment: I want to get the selected text after I click the submit button. I am getting the text with ddlState.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp dropdownlist dynamic value from javascript issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500944/asp-dropdownlist-dynamic-value-from-javascript-issue)

Answer (score -1):

your "change" function should not be inside the GetStates() function. You should collect the value every time the user change the select. and after that trigger the GetStates with the actual value.

```
$(".ddlCountry").change(function () {
         valueOfddlCountry = $(this).val();

});
```

Comment: This is to get the list of states based on the country that i selected.

Comment: Then, when someone change the value of the select you add the value to a variable and pass it to your function like functionName(passValue);